# -webkit-transform desaturating text-shadow

Tags: css, webkit

Consider the following CSS for a `h2` element:

```
h2 {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ff00ff;
}
```

Expectantly, the element should feature a pink text shadow. However, for some reason the `-webkit-transform` property is causing the `text-shadow` colour to become destaurated. I have put this into a jsFiddle so you can see what I mean:

**With `-webkit-transform`:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Wr5St/

**Without `-webkit-transform`:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Wr5St/1/

Does anyone know of a workaround, or what  might be causing this? Removing `-webkit-transform` solves the problem for the shadow, but for obvious reasons isn't an option for me.

Comment: I don't see any differences in the rendered shadow color in both examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the colour as rgba instead?

Comment: Using `rgba()` with anything other than alpha value of 1 works. Setting alpha to 1 still desaturates. I can use 0.99 for now - thanks for your help.